# How can I show a different value apart from the dropdown options in v-select in vue 2 js

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Well the scenario is when the `selectedFruits` is having some element then I need to show "Fruits Selected" and If there is no fruit selected it should display "Select Fruits" in the select. Below is my template and the data I am using. So basically it won't show the fruits selected but display the messages mentioned above in the v-select dropdown. I am new to the vue js, so wondering whether this is possible or not? or is there any alternate way to achieve the same scenario.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select 
      v-model="selectedFruits" 
      :items="fruits" 
      label="name" 
      multiple 
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: [
        { name: 'Apple' },
        { name: 'Mango' },
        { name: 'Banana' },
        { name: 'Berries' },
        { name: 'Muskmelon' }
      ],
      selectedFruits: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's usually when you set a "default" with a value of "" and the desired message when nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that there is an option called selection which we can use with v-slot through which I am able to achieve the desired result. Below is the changes I made in my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select 
      v-model="selectedFruits" 
      :items="fruits" 
      label="Select Fruits" 
      multiple 
    >
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
   <span v-if="index === 0">{{
        item && "Fruits Selected"
    }}</span>
  </template>
 </v-select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: [
        { name: 'Apple' },
        { name: 'Mango' },
        { name: 'Banana' },
        { name: 'Berries' },
        { name: 'Muskmelon' }
      ],
      selectedFruits: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```